# Find all the lines where a specific dict key has a certain value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to find all the lines where a specific dict key has a certain value.
Not really clear said like that, so here is a example :

```
data = [
    {'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'},
    {'key1' : 'value3', 'key2' : 'value4'},
    {'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value5'}
]

out = data['key1' == 'value1']['key2']
```

I would like `out` to be equal to `['value2', 'value5']`, but in fact it returns only the first result, i.e. `'value2'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## *Vanilla* lists and dictionaries

You can use *list comprehension* for this:

```
   [d['key2'] for d in data if d['key1'] == 'value1']
#   \___ ___/ \_____ _____/ \___________ __________/
#       v           v                   v
#     yield      iterator              filter
```

(comments are only used to make it easier to understand the syntax)

So we iterate over `data` with `d` is iterator. We check if `d['key1'] == 'value1'`, if that is the case, we add `d['key2']` to the resulting list.

## Pandas

Pandas is a package that allows to process (large) *dataframes*. Although a dataframe can be very flexible, a basic (and thus not completely correct) definition, is to see it as a 2d table where each row has the same named columns. You can install pandas with:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

(or for [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), `pip install pandas`)

Next we can use pandas by importing it:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Next we can make a dataframe with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

this will look like:

```
>>> df
     key1    key2
0  value1  value2
1  value3  value4
2  value1  value5
```

Now we can obtain a `Series` of `key2` values where `key1` is `'value1'` with:

```
df[df['key1'] == 'value1']['key2']
```

this produces:

```
>>> df[df['key1'] == 'value1']['key2']
0    value2
2    value5
Name: key2, dtype: object
```

Here it is of course much work for a simple result, but pandas can be used to do complex queries in reasonable time over large datasets.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation for others - ran into this issue today (got pointed to this solution before this question was posted) much more elegant / pythonic solution than what I was planning using multiple map / filters

Comment: Thanks Willem! And what about this syntax data['key1' == 'value1']['key2']? I find it quite sexy, is there any way to make it return all the lines that answer to this criteria?

Comment: @Maxime: not with vanilla lists and dictionaries, since `'key1' == 'value1'` is evaluated first. But you have quite similar syntax in Pandas. Will update.

Comment: Perfect, it seams powerfull. Thanks!